# How to include CSS, images, and JavaScript files in Design Package?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-designer, design-manager

I've put my CSS, design images, and JavaScript files inside a folder in my Style Library. How do I include these files in my design package? Should I be storing these assets in a different place?

Comment: Whatever is in your style library will be exported with the Design Manager Pkg

Comment: As long as the files are referenced in your master page and/or page layouts, they'll be included in the design package.

Comment: Also note that the resource files (ex. css, js, png, jpg) need to be published too, or it will take the last published version.